# GKE Kubernetes permission denied

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

Trying to delete a cluster with:

gcloud container clusters delete load-cluster

Output:

```
The following clusters will be deleted.
 - [load-cluster] in [us-east1-b]

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

Deleting cluster load-cluster...done.
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.delete) Could not create directory [C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.kube]: Permission denied.

Please verify that you have permissions to write to the parent directory.
```

Weird part is, it actually gets deleted when I check Google Cloud, but this bug is driving me up the wall.

Comment: After running this command and getting the error run `gcloud feedback` which will guide you to file a issue report. This will likely generate enough info to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Are you running `gcloud` as Administrator? It appears like it's trying to reach out to systemprofile instead of your %userprofile%.

Answer (score 0):

Late, but maybe it will help someone else.
Recently, I faced the same problem running the same "gcloud" command on linux.
And, in my case it looked like following:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.delete) Could not create directory [/~/.kube]: Permission denied.
```

Dir name looked strange to me because it looked like user's home dir was not expanded to full path.
Moreover, I had custom dir for kubeconfig.
Then, I checked env vars in the shell where I had gotten such error and found out that in such case my KUBECONFIG env var was not set.
After setting "KUBECONFIG" env var with proper kubeconfig path and running "gcloud" command with user that has permissions to that dir solved the problem for me.